Is there is any representation of a ERC-1155 token in SPL? Or is possible to mimic it with SPL
So my main question is in description. I want to know is there is any ready to go solution or it might be something hand written. I saw a new programmable NFT in Candy Machine documentation but it's only allows you to customise some rules but not to add custom functionality to it
